# Elastic search how to query the results for the keyword exists in the given fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a email elastic search db created uses following mappings for email sender and receipients:

```
 "mappings": {
   ...
   "recipients": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "sender": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    ...
```

I am given a list of emails and I try to query the emails if the any of the email is either the sender OR recipient. For example, I try to use following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "abc@apple.com defg@samsung.com",
      "operator": "OR",
      "fields": [ "recipients", "sender" ],
      "type": "cross_fields"
    }
  }
}
```

to query the emails if (abc@apple.com exists in the sender or receipient) OR (defg@samsung.com exists in the sender or receipient). But it doesn't return any result.. (But it do exists)

Does anyone know how to query the emails if any of the email in sender or receipient?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good that you have found the solution, but understanding why `multi_match` didn't work and why `query_string` worked, and why you should avoid the `query_string` if possible important.

As mentioned, in the [official Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html),

[image]

Also, your `multi_match` query didn't work as you provided the `two mails` input in the same query like `abc@apple.com defg@samsung.com` and this term is analyzed depending on the fields analyzer(keyword in your example), So, it would try to find `abc@apple.com defg@samsung.com` in your fields, not `abc@apple.com` or `defg@samsung.com`.

**If you want to use the multi_match**, right query would be

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "abc@apple.com",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "fields": [
                            "recipients",
                            "sender"
                        ],
                        "type": "cross_fields"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "defg@samsung.com",
                        "operator": "OR",
                        "fields": [
                            "recipients",
                            "sender"
                        ],
                        "type": "cross_fields"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

which returns below documents.

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "71367024",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.6931471,
                "_source": {
                    "recipients": "abc@apple.com",
                    "sender": "foo@bar.com"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "71367024",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.6931471,
                "_source": {
                    "recipients": "defg@samsung.com",
                    "sender": "baz@bar.com"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I may find the answer. Using the following query will work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string" : {
      "query":    "abc@apple.com OR defg@samsung.com",
      "fields": [ "recipients", "sender" ]
    }
  }
```